# Trying to awk a file, but cannot allocate sufficient memory. Any alternatives or adjustments?

Tags: bash, awk

The file in question is a pileup file from RNAseq. I want to extract information on one chromosome. This has worked for smaller files:

```
awk '/chrM/ { print }' file1.pileup > file1.chrm.pileup
```

The error code:

```
awk: (FILENAME=file1.pileup FNR=1743118775) fatal: grow_iop_buffer: iop->buf: can't allocate 137438953474 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Is there an alternative command, or a sub-command to circumvent this?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Data looks like this:

```
chr1    258755  T       1       .                 F
chr1    258756  C       1       ......            F
chr1    258757  T       1       ...               H
chr1    258758  A       1       ...........       H
```

It is 3529769718150 bytes.

I expect to find (basically a bunch of rows between ~70-75% of the way down):

```
chrM    6432       C       1       ^~.            B
chrM    7294       A       1       ........       B
chrM    7296       G       1       .....          B
```

Edit2:

Output of 'head -n 1 File1 | od -c':

```
0000000   c   h   r   1  \t   2   5   8   7   4   9  \t   T  \t   1  \t
0000020   ^   ~   .  \t   C  \n
0000026
```

Output of 'head -c xxx File1 | od -c':

```
head: xxx: invalid number of bytes
0000000
```

Output of 'head -c 100 File1 | od -c':

```
0000000   c   h   r   1  \t   2   5   8   7   4   9  \t   T  \t   1  \t
0000020   ^   ~   .  \t   C  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   2   5   8   7   5
0000040   0  \t   T  \t   1  \t   .  \t   C  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   2
0000060   5   8   7   5   1  \t   T  \t   1  \t   G  \t   C  \n   c   h
0000100   r   1  \t   2   5   8   7   5   2  \t   T  \t   1  \t   .  \t
0000120   F  \n   c   h   r   1  \t   2   5   8   7   5   3  \t   C  \t
0000140   1  \t   .  \t
0000144
```

Comment: This indicates your file doesn't contain `CR` as line delimiters, so the complete file seen as one line to be buffered.  Otherwise these tools are designed to work line by line, independent of the file size.

Comment: @karakfa Is there any action I can take over this?

Comment: Try `head -n 1 your_file | od -c` and see if you can see what the line delimiters are. You may be dealing with a binary file. Or, try `head -c xxx your_file | od -c` to read 100 characters and see if you can see what character is the line ending.

Comment: Maybe not `head -n 1` but `head -c 100` if there is a line-ending problem.

Comment: @JamesBrown: good idea

Comment: That's a big file. Can you even `wc your_file` ?

Comment: @glennjackman Tried, was taking too long so gave up.

Comment: Which awk and version are you using? `awk -V`

Comment: @JamesBrown GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: That's pretty old. Could you perhaps upgrade it to a more recent on?

Comment: @JamesBrown I would think it unlikely, I'm using a university computing cluster. I doubt they would update things solely for my benefit and if there's other means I don't have the know how.

Comment: Are there other awks available, mawk for example? You could also download and compile from the source.

Comment: I seem to have access to 'gawk' if this is better? I have done a little compiling etc. in the past with assistance from other staff but try to avoid it. May have to explore that option.

Comment: @karakfa the error message includes `FNR=1743118775` which indicates there are CR in the input since awk has read that many lines. The only options AFAIK are that there is a single massive line at line 1743118775 (or 6) of the OPs data or there is a bug in the version of gawk the OP is running and if so he needs to get a newer version of gawk.

Comment: Looks like there's a discussion of this bug here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2003-04/msg00008.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your grep command might not be able to deal with files larger than 2.4 GB because the 32 bit pointer can't access them.

Try running

split --line-bytes=2GB file1.pileup

This will split your file into two pieces that you should be able to process as you'd like.

Comment: To my eyes this seems to have worked. To confirm, this command gave me a collection of files called `x**`. I then ran my usual command over all of them:      `awk '/chrM/ { print }' x** > chrm.pileup`. This is what you had in mind?

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon (I had attempted to dupicate the file to test commands on, something must have been left behind). In theory everything seems sound, but `split: output file suffixes exhausted`. If I can customise the output suffixes I think I'm good to go.

Comment: Presuming that splitting the file was the ticket, grepping as others have suggested is usually a more efficient way to select lines. If you need to select individual fields as well, you may find it easier to use cut than awk. Awk is very powerful, but sometimes it's faster and easier to go with a more specialized utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `grep -F` (fixed text search) here instead of `awk`:

```
grep -wF 'chrM' file1.pileup > file1.chrm.pileup
```

If you really want to use `awk` then faster & shorter command would be avoiding regex:

```
awk 'index($0, "chrM")' file1.pileup > file1.chrm.pileup
```

Comment: Thanks. Grep gives me the same memory issues. Will try your second solution now.

Comment: perhaps add `w` switch as well, to eliminate substring matches.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa I have added it though OP's `/chrM/` was also not addressing it.

Comment: @FatBerg: If you provide a reproducible input then these solutions can be tested.

Comment: I don't see how I can do so. My problem is the size of the data set. The format of the data can be found above.

Comment: @FatBerg all of the commands discussed so far are taking your data 1 line at a time so how many lines long your data is is irrelevant. The only way your data could be causing this problem is if there is a single line in the data that's absolutely massive. if you think that may be the case then do divide and conquer on your input to isolate that line.

Comment: @EdMorton, data is accessed only one line at a time, but I think his file pointer can't deal with anything beyond 32 bits. If that is the case as it appears, breaking the file into smaller chunks will magically make the problem go away. His data file is 3.5TB.

Comment: @KyleBanerjee could be but there is a known bug in GNU awk around that version that exhibits that behavior so maybe it's that? The OPs awk version is WAY out of date so he should update it anyway and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you'll have better success avoiding regular expressions:

```
awk '$1 == "chrM"' file1.pileup > file1.chrm.pileup
```

---

I wonder if your file got "corrupted", and somewhere in the file there's one line
 that is 137438953474 bytes long. Can you try this:

```
awk '{print NR, NF, length($0)}' file1.pileup > file1.line_lengths
```

And see where it craps out?

Comment: Same issue sadly.

Comment: Can't allocate enough memory for that either.

Comment: Yes but what's the last line of the output file?

Comment: And what is the average number of fields and line length up to that point?

Comment: You might need to add an fflush() to make sure the last line processed before the crash gets output.

Comment: @glennjackman The last line (minus the comand suggested by Ed Morton) is `1743118775 6 34`. I do not know how to find the other information but I will google.

Comment: My guess is that the first 1.7 billion lines of the file are "normal" with 6 fields per line. Then the file became corrupted at that point so that the next line is either full of garbage or somehow newlines have been lost. Kyle's `split` solution looks like your most practical method of recovery.